# What does this JSON response mean?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am following a MEVN stack tutorial: https://appdividend.com/2018/11/21/mevn-stack-tutorial-with-example-from-scratch/#8_Setup_and_connect_MongoDB_database

In section 10 he shows how to create routes for adding, deleting, updating and reading data in a mongoDB database using mongoose.

```
This is part of that code:
// post.model.js

const express = require('express');
const postRoutes = express.Router();

// Require Post model in our routes module
let Post = require('./post.model');

// Defined store route
postRoutes.route('/add').post(function (req, res) {
  let post = new Post(req.body);
  post.save()
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json({'business': 'business in added successfully'});
    })
    .catch(() => {
      res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
});
```

Is there a specific reason he has put `{'business': 'business in added successfully'}` in the JSON for the 200 response? or can that just be anything? Also i'm not entirely sure what i would put in it for my specific scenario where i am trying to add, delete, update and read data about users in a 'users' collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be anything, just to information that received request is successful and created the records. He added some response to that request.